# Add class to child if has same numeric class as parent

Tags: html, jquery, css

I need to add class to child if has the same numeric class as parent, or I need to remove the children of parent if does not have the same numeric class. So in my example if child has class post-55 and parent has same class, I will add a class visible to child. I get this error: Cannot read property '1' of null.

```js
jQuery( 'article' ).each( function() {
 var parent_id = jQuery(this).attr('class').match(/post-(\d+)/)[1];
  var child_id = jQuery(this).children('div').attr('class').match(/post-(\d+)/)[1];
  
  if ( child_id == parent_id ) {
  jQuery(this).children('div').addClass('visible');
}
              });
```

```css
article {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background: red;
 margin:20px;
}
.inner {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 margin:20px;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<article class="post-45">
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-44 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
</article>
<article class="post-55">
  <div class="post-34 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
</article>
<article class="post-34">
  <div class="post-34 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
</article>
```

Comment: Your code works without any errors in this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4h2w908m/

Comment: yes but its still not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you create an `each()` function for the divs inside each article:

```js
jQuery('article').each(function() {
  var parent_id = jQuery(this).attr('class').match(/post-(\d+)/)[1];
  jQuery(this).children('div').each(function() {
    var child_id = jQuery(this).attr('class').match(/post-(\d+)/)[1];
    if (child_id == parent_id) {
      jQuery(this).addClass('visible');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
article {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background: red;
 margin:20px;
}
.inner {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 margin:20px;
 background: black;
 display:none;
}
.visible {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="post-45">
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-44 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
</article>
<article class="post-55">
  <div class="post-34 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
</article>
<article class="post-34">
  <div class="post-34 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
</article>
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. but I still get this error: Cannot read property '1' of null. I don't know why

Comment: @art It's working in this Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4h2w908m/1/ without any errors, tested in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I believe you, but its not working on my side, the code is the same

Answer (score 1):

A better implementation would be like the following, grab the class attribute of the article using [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/), then use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) on the element selected inside the `.each()` function to select the matching child, here is a working snippet:

```js
$( 'article' ).each(function(i, el){
  let elClass = $(el).attr('class');
  $(el).find(`.${elClass}`).addClass('visibile');
});
```

```css
article {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 background: red;
 margin:20px;
}
.inner {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 margin:20px;
 background: black;
 display:none;
}
.visibile {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<article class="post-45">
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-44 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
</article>
<article class="post-55">
  <div class="post-34 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
</article>
<article class="post-34">
  <div class="post-34 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-45 inner"></div>
  <div class="post-55 inner"></div>
</article>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```